# Fetching related objects data from standardcontroller extension into visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller

```
public class TrackerExt {
    public String OpportunityId {get;set;}
    private final Opportunity opp;
    public List<Tracker__c> trackers{get; set;}

    public TrackerExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
           this.opp = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
    }
    public List<Tracker__c> fetchTracker(){
        trackers= [Select Name, Createddate, Object__c from Tracker__c where opportunity__c=:opp.id];
        return trackers;    
    }
}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="TrackerExt">

     <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Tracker</title>
              ID: {!OpportunityId}
             Opp: {!trackers[0].Opportunity__c}

      /------Will use trackers list of objects to use for a table here../


     </head>
</apex:page>
```

I don't get any data in the collection returned. I simply tried to print, use in pageblock and alert in JS.
I am adding this page in opportunity page layout.

```
  (function(){
            var temp = '{!trackers[0].name}';
             var abc = '{!trackers[0].object__c}';
                alert(abc); })();
```

Comment: are you passing correct Opportunity Id from URL?

Comment: Thanks Santanu. I am using this page within opportunity page layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the `Tracker__c` objects by using merge syntax (`{!trackers}`).  This implicitly looks for a method called `getTrackers()` in the controller and extensions.  I think if you re-name your `fetchTracker()` method to `getTrackers()` and get rid of the `{get; set;}` attribute called 'trackers' you should be fine.

Alternatively you can invoke the `fetchTracker()` function from within your constructor, which assigns the list to the `{get; set;}` attribute called 'trackers'.